# How do I remove a manually installed GPU driver in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, xorg

As seen below "Additional Drivers" claim I have a manually installed driver.

[image: Additional Drivers]

I want to go back to not having "manually installed" driver anymore in this GUI, but they are all greyed out.

**What I've done:**

- I did uninstall the manually installed driver with:

  ```
  sudo nvidia-uninstall
  ```

  and followed the instructions, then rebooted.
- I purged everything `nvidia` with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
  sudo apt-get remove --purge libnvidia-*
  ```
- I also ran the uninstaller from the file I installed the manual driver to begin with:

  ```
  sudo NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-418.43.run --uninstall
  ```
- I've updated through `apt`, rebooted 3 times.

**What I've not done and why:**

I can't find `xorg.conf` anywhere on my system so I've not deleted that.

**Graphics info in terminal**

[image: Graphics info in terminal]

So can someone please help me find how to make it possible to choose a driver in the GUI again without having to reinstall the entire OS?

Comment: find installed package by name : `dpkg -l | grep -i 'nvidia'`

Comment: Yes I did that to know what to purge and to make sure it was gone. There's no packages containing nvidia anymore.

Comment: It looks like you've successfully removed the Nvidia software, and are running on the open-source nouveau driver right now. What does the `Additional Drivers` tab say now?

Comment: It's exactly as the picture. It is the nouveau drivers showing there, it just claims that they are manually installed. I've not done anything extra since posting the question. I also confirmed in question that it's the nouveau drivers as you can see in the bottom picture.

Comment: I did `sudo apt-get remove --purge *-nvidia-*` in addition to the other `--purge` commands above

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was in the same situation. I had done everything as you. What did the "trick" after all that steps is this command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Then I rebooted the system and I was able to use the proprietary Nvidia driver again.

Comment: This worked for me when I run it from root user. However, links to install software lost. So I had to install all the software again even Ubuntu Software center and many

Comment: Works for 22.04.1, though the command is `install`, not `autoinstall` anymore (that one was deprecated.. check with `ubuntu-drivers --help`).

Comment: `autoinstall` worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Answer (score 1):

What [worked](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/zbbb5f/solution_attention_nvidia_users_if_your_system_is/?rdt=36781) for me was:

1)In the terminal:

```
sudo apt remove nvidia-*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

2)Then manually select the driver you want to switch to in the Additional Drivers app

3)Reboot

4)Then in the terminal:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

5)Happy days.