# Additional drivers inaccessible (unavailable) after some updates - Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, updates, 22.04

[image: Additional drivers utility]

Please help me to figure out why after some updates additional drivers had become unavailable?
It tells me that at this time it is used manually installed drivers - not even Nouveau driver. Is it OK?

And if it's not normal how can I revert to previous state? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This state means that you have installed some proprietary driver that is not available in current repositories. Maybe you installed one from a PPA or some other way.

You can keep using the current driver, or install one of the recommended ones.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But how do I find this driver and safely uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have found an easy solution for this problem.

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

This updates all drivers, removes manually installed and after that all drivers become accessible.

This question/answer helped me:

[How do I remove manually installed gpu driver in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127187/how-do-i-remove-manually-installed-gpu-driver-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Thank you very much!